# I am trying to print some text from a file by read(), but it is not showing

Tags: python-3.x

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print(f"We're going to erase {filename}")
print("If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).")
print("If you do want that, hit RETURN.")

input("?")

print("Opening the file...")
target = open(filename, 'r+')

print("Truncating the file.  Goodbye!")
target.truncate()

print("Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.")

line1 = input("line1 : ")
line2 = input("line2 : ")
line3 = input("line3 : ")

print("I'm going to write these to the file.")

target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3 + "\n")
print("I'm going to read the file to you.")
read = target.read()
print(read)

print("And finally, we close it.")
target.close()
```

I wrote some text by this script on a file(which is test.txt), and I wanted to print out the text by using read(). Due to the fact there is no error sign, I kept my code and did some different(silly) things, but my script is still not printing the text from the file. Please help me.

Comment: close the file after you write to it, then re-open it to read it.  2 line change...

Comment: Thank you so much!! If you don't mid, could you explain why the file has to be closed and re-opened to be read?

Comment: python keeps a pointer to the place in an open file that only resets when closed.  So if you don't close, you start reading after the last write, which is empty.

Comment: That is very kind of you! Thank you so much!!